# Gtk-warning: Invalid text buffer iterator when writing to the same text view multiple times

Tags: c, gtk

This below function gets called every second and tries to write the total_successful_connects.
It works sometimes but I get the above error and program crashes.

gtk_text_buffer_set_text() will delete the previous buffer content. Does it not validate the iterator?

If not, What should I do to validate the iterator?

```
void display_status()
{
    char output_str[100];

    sprintf(output_str, "%u", stats->total_successful_connects);
    gtk_text_buffer_set_text(
        config->text_buffer,
        output_str, strlen(output_str));

}
```

I have initialized config->textbuffer once during start up by calling gtk_text_view_get_buffer(my_text_view)

I am using gtk+ 2

Error in detail:

```
(gedit:7793): Gtk-WARNING **: Invalid text buffer iterator: either the iterator is uninitialized, or the characters/pixbufs/widgets in the buffer have been modified since the iterator was created.
You must use marks, character numbers, or line numbers to preserve a position across buffer modifications.
You can apply tags and insert marks without invalidating your iterators,
but any mutation that affects 'indexable' buffer contents (contents that can be referred to by character offset)
will invalidate all outstanding iterators
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `gdk_threads_add_idle()` to schedule the call to `gtk_text_buffer_set_text()` in the main thread. Like this:

```
struct DispatchData {
    GtkTextBuffer *buffer;
    char *output_str;
};

static gboolean display_status_textbuffer(struct DispatchData *data)
{
    gtk_text_buffer_set_text(data->buffer, data->output_str, strlen(data->output_str));
    g_free(data);
    return G_SOURCE_REMOVE;
}

void display_status()
{
    struct DispatchData *data = g_new0(struct DispatchData, 1);
    data->output_str = g_strdup_printf("%u", stats->total_successful_connects);
    data->buffer = config->buffer;
    gdk_threads_add_idle(display_status_textbuffer, data);
}
```

(This is assuming that you do more non-GUI work in `display_status()` than just what you showed above; otherwise it would make sense to have just one every-second function that you initiate with `gdk_threads_add_timeout()`.

Comment: display_status() runs in a separate thread other than one that runs gtk main loop.

Although, the separate thread I use will do only GUI work

Comment: You can't do GUI work in a separate thread. Well, you can using `gdk_threads_enter()`, but you'll just have to rewrite it when you upgrade to a later GTK version, since that way of doing things is discouraged and deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't update the GUI from within the thread.
You can assign a timeout to your GUI window using "g_timeout_add" and get it to call a function that updates your GUI (from your main program).
Your thread can update values, but the function called by the timeout can update the textbuffers.

```
cog_timeout_add(1000, (GSourceFunc) time_handler, (gpointer) window) ;
```

--->place this above your gtk_widget_show(window)
--->then place the command to force it not to wait the first second

```
time_handler(window) ;
```

Then in your main program write the function it calls.

```
static gboolean time_handler(GtkWidget *widget) {
    gtk_text_buffer_set_text (textbuffer, stufftosay, -1) ;
    return TRUE ;
}
```

Comment: is it g_timeout_add or cog_timeout_add?
You code sample reads cog_timeout_add, preceded by "co"